# logical error, not giving the wanted answer

Tags: java

I don't understand what I did wrong, there's no syntax error, but it's not giving out the answer I want. The algorithm is supposed to find the integer between 1 and 10000 to have the largest number of divisors, and state how many divisors it contains.

```
public class pract3ex11 {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    int n;
    int i;
    int c=0;
    int max=0;
    int result;
    int d;
    for (n=2; n<10000; n++){
        d=c;
        c=0;
        int x=n;
        result = x;
        for (i=1; i<x; i++){


            result= result%i;
            if (result==0){
                c++;
            }

            if (c>d){
                max=n;

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max+" "+c);

}
```

Comment: This type of question is more easily answered when you specify (a) what you were expecting; and (b) what you got.

Comment: Use variable names, that actually tell, what is contained. Your current naming makes it quite hard to understand the logic!

Comment: Also, you realize professors have been browsing Stack Overflow.

Comment: If your professor wants to maintain their sanity, they would have stopped browsing four years ago

Comment: Lol, not mine, just have seen the posts of people getting caught, and wanted to give a heads up =P  Haven't been in college for a few years now.

Comment: But seriously, your variable names are terrible. `n` could be `currently_inspected`, `i` could be `potential_divisor`, `c` could be `current_divisor_count`, `max` could be `max_divisor_count`, `d` could be ... what the hell is `d` doing?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm still new to how the site works

Answer (score 3):

When you set the `max`, you should also set `d`. Otherwise, the two get out of sync:

```
if (c>d){
    d = c;
    max=n;
}
```

You also need to assign `0` to `d` *before* the loop, and remove

```
d=c;
```

at the top of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      int count; 
      int maxDivisors;  
      int number;  
      maxDivisors = 1;  
      number = 1;
  for ( count = 2;  count  <= 10000;  count ++ ) {
         int x;  
         int divisors = 0;
      for ( x = 1;  x <= count;  x++ ) { 
        if ( count % x == 0 )
            divisors++;
          }

          if (divisors > maxDivisors) {
              maxDivisors = divisors;
              number = count;
          }

      }

      System.out.println("The maximum number of divisors are " + maxDivisors);
      System.out.println("Number is : " + number);
   }
```